# Is my code correct? UML-> Java translation

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, uml, addition

I was just going through some examples of UML diagramms, being translated in Java, and I am stuck at this one. 
I am giving the diagramm as a reference:

[image: UML]

Since I am very new at Java programming there is something I don't understand in this code : why do I have to add LinkedList? What does the T:Tier at the right corner of Gehege mean? (Gehege=Zoo, Tiere=Animals in German)

```
public class Tier {
    private int anzahlbeine;
    private String farbe;

    public Tier(int anzahlbeine, String farbe) {
        this.anzahlbeine=anzahlbeine;
        this.farbe=farbe;
    }

    public void laufen (double strecke) {
        System.out.println(strecke);
    }

    public void fressen () {
        System.out.println("I eat");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Gehege <T extends Tier> {
    private int kapazitaet;
    private double groesse;
    private LinkedList<T> tiere;

    public Gehege(int kapazitaet, double groesse) {
        this.kapazitaet=kapazitaet; 
        this.groesse=groesse;
    }

    public void addTier(T tier) {
        if (this.kapazitaet>this.groesse.size) {
            this.tiere.add(tiere);
        }
        else { throw new Exception RunTimeException ("Full"); }
    }

    public void removeTier(T tier){
        this.tiere.remove(tier);}
}
```

Better Quality image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/subAS.png

Comment: `throw new Exception RunTimeException ("Full");` There is no way this line compiles. Your indentation and bracket placement really throws me off. Try to be consistent about where you put them. At a quick glance though, your code coheres to the provided UML diagram (at least from what you provided)

Answer (score 0):

What does the T:Tier at the right corner of Gehege mean?

That means `Gehege` is templatized with `Tier`. Though everything is syntactically correct, semantically it is not right. Can be there different kinds of `Gehege`s holding different kinds of things? That does not look very much right!

Take an example of `List`. `List` is templatized because there can be lists of different kinds of objects like - `List` of `Car`, `List` of `Book` etc. Apply the same thing to `Gehege` - the logic falls flat. Therefore in my opinion the design is not semantically right.

Comment: Why not? I may be misinterpreting this, but doesn't it make sense to have a `Gehege` (zoo) of `Elefant`s (elephants), or a `Gehege` of `Tausendfuessler`s?

Comment: Going by that what about the general case of a `Gehege` having `Elefants` and `Tigers`? How do you implement it using this model?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the multi-valued reference property `tiere` of type `LinkedList<T>` to the class `Gehege` for implementing the association/aggregation between `Gehege` and `Tier` that associates many `Tier` instances with one `Gehege` instance. By convention, the name of this property is the lowercased and pluralized name of the associated class (`Tier`).

In fact, it's preferable to refrain from making a choice of `LinkedList` versus `ArrayList` by using the `List` interface as the type of the multi-valued reference property. Consequently, it should be rather

```
public class Gehege <T extends Tier> {
  ...
  private List<T> tiere;
  ...
}
```